# Using python and selenium how can i get the value of placeholder where the value is not utf-8?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide

I was trying to get the email address and click on the refresh button from the following screenshot. But I am getting errors.

[image]

My code for this is like the following:

```
from selenium import webdriver
url = 'http://od.obagg.com/ '

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver')
driver.get(url)

s = driver.find_element_by_id('//*[@id="shortid"]').get_attribute('placeholder')
print(s)
```

Based on the inspect, i was trying to do and tried many ways to get that email field value and click on refresh button. But still no luck.

Do anybody know any tricks to share?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be due to the fact the element is disabled, also, `find_element_by_id('//*[@id="shortid"]')` is incorrect. It can be either:

- `find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="shortid"]')`
- `find_element_by_id("shortid")` ?

The following works for me:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver')
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('http://od.obagg.com/')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
el = wait.until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "shortid")))
placeholder = el.get_attribute("placeholder")
email = el.get_attribute('value')
print(placeholder, email)
# 请等待分配临时邮箱 -_ylp06tc@xxx.xxx
```

---

If you need 10 different emails, you can use:

```
from time import sleep
for x in range(10):
    driver.find_element_by_id("refreshShortid").click()
    sleep(0.15) # you may have to increase this value to give enough time to generate the new email
    new_email = driver.find_element_by_id("shortid").get_attribute('value')
    print(new_email)
```

Comment: is there any way to get the value of the email which is readable?

Comment: i did, but the email is still printing 请等待分配临时邮箱 . its not plain english.

Comment: I cannot reproduce that, make sure you copy the code exactly as in the answer and you should have the same results as me, which show the correct emails address.